# Spring boot JPA - What is the best solution for updating the intermediate table of ManyToMany relationship with extra columns in the Controller?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I am using Spring Boot for backend in my project. In the database (MySQL) I have a many-to-many relationship which has the next entities: User, interest and relUserInterest. The RelUserInterest is a intermediate table between User and Interest and has extra columns.

*User Entity*

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
     
    @NotNull
    @Column (unique = true) private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();

    // more attributes, constructor, get and set
}
```

*Interest entity*

```
@Entity
public class Interest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nameInterest;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "interest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();

    // more attributes, constructor, get and set
}
```

*RelUserInterest entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rel_user_interest")
@IdClass(UserInterestId.class)
public class RelUserInterest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    User user;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "interest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Interest interest;

    int priority;

    //  constructor, get and set
}
```

So far so good. I want to update the user and their interests. My controller is this. I want to do is when I update a existing user, update the intermediate table (RelUserInterest).

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@Validated @RequestBody UserDTOUpdate userDTOUpdate, BindingResult result, @PathVariable Long id) {
        // More code
        User user = usersService.getUserById(id);
        
        // Code updating other attributes

        // Here this the problem --> I don't know how to update the attribute priority of RelUserInterest

        usersService.updateUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Mensaje("Usuario actualizado"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

I have found several links but I'm not sure which is the best solution and I don't know how do it with my code.

- [How to update ManyToMany with extra columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210014/how-to-update-manytomany-with-extra-columns)
- [Spring boot JPA many to many with extra column insert and update
  issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967761/spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-with-extra-column-insert-and-update-issue)
- [Spring-Data-JPA ManyToMany relationship with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648330/spring-data-jpa-manytomany-relationship-with-extra-column/52654305#52654305)

In the Postman i want to send the next JSON although the interest array can be different if it is necessary for the solution:

```
{
    "age": 22,
    "genre": "Male",
    "userName": "Miguel",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_ADMIN",
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "interest": [
        {
            "interestID": 1,
            "nameInterest": "Museum",
            "priority": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

### Question

So, the question is: How can I update the attribute priority of the RelUserEntity table? I suppose that making an intermediate table repository is a mistake. I'm a little lost. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Looking at your update request, the `priority` field should be  an attribute of `Interest `, it could simplify your problem. Also nothing  stops you to use  `RelUserInterestRepository` to update the  related field.

Comment: Is it a good practice if I add an repository of intermediate table? @akuma8

Comment: Since you have an entity associated to your table, I don't see another simple way to use its repository interface to manipulate it

Comment: Take a look here https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-hsql/

Comment: Ok. I will do so. Thank you very much to both of you